# How to illuminate the edges of an object in the bge

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

[image: e.]

First of all, I don't know if this is what I should call that effect. I'd like to illuminate an object's edges once the object is detected by a ray sensor in the game engine. For example, I'd like the edges to turn red when the ray sensor hits an enemy. Ive been looking up tutorials, but I haven't found anything. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no build-in option that provides you an outline effect.

But there are other options. E.g. via GLSL shaders.

Additionally you can create an similar outline by

- duplicating the mesh,
- scaling it up a little,
- assigning it green shadeless color

(This will not result in a one pixel outline.)